# How can I use a PV of one kubernetes custer in another k8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, volume, kubernetes-pvc

I have an AWS EKS cluster. Lets call it EKS-1, in which I had a stateful set with a PVC and PV that provisioned a EBS volume in AWS dynamically. I deleted the Stateful set and the PVC. The PV is in available status and its volume in AWS is also intact.

Now I have a second cluster EKS-2 in which I have deployed a stateful set that created a PVC and a PV. Now I want to use the AWS EBS volume created by EKS-1 as a PV for the staefulsset in EKS-2.

How can we do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You have **Two** options either you use the same **EBS** volume to **EKS** **cluster-2** or you clone the data from **EKS-1 EBS** to **EKS-2** **EBS**(new volume but data cloned).

**Option : 1**

Before you move ahead make sure **PVC** is not **attached** to **PV** for **EKS-1** cluster, we will use this **EBS** volume to **EKS-2** cluster.

Create the YAML config and apply

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-data
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    fsType: ext4
    volumeID: aws://eu-west-2a/Vol_Details
  capacity:
    storage: 60Gi
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: gp2
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: <app-name>
  name: pvc-name
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 60Gi
  storageClassName: gp2
  volumeName: pv-data
```

Once you create the **PV** with existing **EBS** volume you will be able to create the **PVC** also & further you will be able to create **statefulsets** and use it.

**Option : 2**

Cloning the data across Cluster

You can leverage the Tool like **velero**, to clone the data. Which will take the snapshot of your **EBS** on **EKS-1** save config data to Bucket, on **EKS-2** you will setup velero and restore those data details from Bucket.

You will be able to take full snapshot also **PV**, **PVC**, **Statefulset** also or single resource also as per need.

Here you can follow my article using the **Velero**, i have used the GCS plugin but you can use the **AWS** & **S3** option instead : https://medium.com/@harsh.manvar111/backup-and-restore-elasticsearch-using-gcs-fa70003b9b5e